# SOQL Inner query pageblocktable

Tags: soql, query, pageblocktable, inner-join, childrecords

I have Application object and References as Child object.

I want to display list of Applications and corresponding "number of References records" for each application in VF Page. There is a status picklist field in References with values - Confirmed & Completed.  I want to display something like below

```
  Application Name   Confirmed References   Completed References

           ABC                1                      1

           XYZ                2                      1
```

---

With the below query I'm able to get the total count of completed and confirmed references count together but not Individual count as above.  How do I get the individual confirmed and completed count for each application in a simple way!

```
List<Application__c> ReviewList = [SELECT Id,Name,(SELECT Id,Name,Status__c FROM References__r WHERE (Status__c = 'Complete' OR Status__c = 'Confirmed'))
                                       FROM Application__c];
```

---

The references__r.size below gives the total count of the records returned in the Inner Query (in this case count of confirmed & completed records together).

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ReviewList}" var="item">
   <apex:column headerValue="Application Name">
       <apex:outputText value="{!item.Name}" />
   </apex:column>
   <apex:column headerValue="References">
       <apex:outputText value="{!item.References__r.size}" />
   </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Answer (score 3):

There can be two solutions

1. **Apex based**:- retrieve all related records in apex and then perform aggregation in apex.

Basically, extract all required records and their references (completed or confirmed)

```
[SELECT Id,Name,(SELECT Id,Name,Status__c FROM References__r WHERE (Status__c = 'Complete' OR Status__c = 'Confirmed'))
                                       FROM Application__c];
```

Iterate over all records in apex code to calculate aggregated values

2. **SOQL + Formula fields**:- Create two formula fields (of type number) within "References__c" custom object

   - *Complete = Should return 1 if "status__c = Complete"*
   - *Confirmed = Should return 1 if "status__c = Confirmed"*

Use following SOQL query to extract application record along with completed and confirmed references (verify field names):-

```
SELECT Application__r.Name, SUM(IsComplete), SUM(IsConfirmed) FROM References__c WHERE (Status__c = 'Complete' OR Status__c = 'Confirmed')
GROUP BY Application__r.Name
```

Considering performance of formula fields in SOQL query, if data volume is high, I would recommend using first approach.